# Issues with CSS

Tags: html, css

I have a sidebar and a content area on my HTML. I want my side bar set on left so what I did is `float:left` while my content area is on `float:right`

My problem is that, the content area goes underneath the sidebar instead of right.

**CSS**

```css
#sidebar{
    width:200px;
    float:left;
    background:black;
}

#sidebar_title{
    background:white;
    color:black;
    font-size:22px;
    font-family: arial;
    padding:10px;
    text-align: center;
}

#content_area{
    width:1000px;
    background:pink;
    float:right;
}

.content_wrapper{
    width:1000px;
    margin:auto;
    background:pink;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="content_wrapper">
    <div id="sidebar"> 
        <div id="sidebar_title"> Categories</div>
    </div>
    <div id="content_area"> content</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your #content_area is too wide...you can't fit 200 + 1000 into a 1000 container...it's basic math.

```css
* {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
#sidebar {
  width: 200px;
  float: left;
  background: black;
}
#sidebar_title {
  background: white;
  color: black;
  font-size: 22px;
  font-family: arial;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
}
#content_area {
  width: 800px;
  background: pink;
  float: right;
}
.content_wrapper {
  width: 1000px;
  margin: auto;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="content_wrapper">
  <div id="sidebar">
    <div id="sidebar_title">Categories</div>
  </div>
  <div id="content_area">content</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I hate math lol. Anyway, thanks :) This fixed it up :). I'll check this post after 6 minutes :)